# I would like to ask why does my Ubuntu searches sources from links NOT in Software and Updates repository list

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, repository, 23.10

So, today the upgrade to Ubuntu 23.10 has arrived, and I was using 23.04, but I don't understand where could these links possibly be stored in, but I keep seeing certain repositories, some of which are broken ones, are NOT in the repository list in Software & Updates, but keeps being used by any repository checking process, like in Synaptic Package Manager, then in Terminal whenever I use `apt update`, only to see them reporting about same errors retrieving something, and now whenever I try to upgrade Ubuntu, I couldn't possibly complete "Setting new software channels", I keep receiving probably about the same errors, definitely with the same links, then the Distribution upgrade just turn to "Restoring to the original state". The log I copied from the Distribution upgrade is like this:

`W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.atlasvpn.com/debian stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386', E:The repository 'https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com lunar Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:GPG error: https://repo.ivpn.net/stable/ubuntu ./generic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D437F3E150DB096C, E:The repository 'https://repo.ivpn.net/stable/ubuntu ./generic InRelease' is not signed.`

So, can you guys suggest to me where could these repositories possibly be stored, if not in the "Software and Updates" nor in thr `sources.list`, or how can I complete the "Setting new software channels" phase? Or my Ubuntu just got broken?

I tried using `sudo apt-add-repository -r` then adding each of these repositories above next but none of them are stopped from being used in the Terminal.

I also tried checking `etc\apt\sources.list` but couldn't find them either.

Comment: It may help to edit your question to clarify what you actually are asking. Use shorter sentences and try to be more concise. Do not assume that readers immediately understand what you mean by "these links".

Comment: Okay, I'll see, it may be understandable if these were intended for Debian, but I already started to try to find ways, and where to remove them as well, if Synaptic and Software Update could somehow 'retrieve" them by the way. Hope I don't annoy or disturb you guys, or hope you guys could help or tell me something you know or spectaculate. (Now I also wonder if any of these repositories preventing me from upgrading were not intended for Ubuntu nor Debian, or just empty, unless I could uninstall some packages or flatpak or snaps.)

Comment: They could very well be in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: I've done upgrading to 23.10. I started Files/Nautilus as root then delete the source files in .list.

Answer (score 0):

ALL your apt sources are listed in these two (TWO!) locations.

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

If a source is listed in your `apt update`, then it is somewhere in those locations. Browse around; you will find it.